# How can i retrive elements to make a match between two given txt files?

Tags: python

I'm doing a project and got stuck in this part. The project consists in a program that matches individuals retrived from two diferent files (two .txts). They match if some atributes are the same between them (for instance, region, hours available, etc).

The thing is, the given files have the individuals ordered by lines and in phrases, splited by commas (name, region, ...). I must convert the informations individually in lists so i can acess their elements. However i cant. To explain myself easily, the given part of the txt with individuals information is organized like this:

function:

```
...
in_file.readline()
individuals = in_file.readline().strip().replace("\n", "")
return (..., individuals) - (in tuples)
```

So far, i could only extract the first individual. I cant do a "loop" for the rest of them to be analyzed.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance. Hope i could give an idea of what im trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, could you please include some sample data. Secondly, why not use for loops?
Thirdly, `readline()` usually stops at `\n`, so we can assume, that `\n` is at the end of your line where `strip()` will remove it, hence no need for replacing it.

The general strategy I apply in the following two functions is:

1. Read the Textfile into an array of lines
2. Extract the Atrributes by splitting at predefined characters and put them into a list of dicts.

Assuming you are running Python 3 (sorry for my bad exception handling):

```
def read_inp(file_name: str, *kwds:str) -> list:
#scans an file for Keywords and returns a list of all the lines starting with any of the given kwds
return_lines = []
try:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f: #open file
        for line in f:
           if line.startswith(*kwds):#check if line starts with one of the keywords
               return_lines.append(
                   line.rstrip() #remove trailing whitespaces, etc.
                   )
    return return_lines    
except Exception as exception:
    pass
```

You can replace the `"="` by any char that is in between your attribute's name and 
 its value

```
def extract_attributes(lines: list, separator = ',') -> list:
#splits lines into smaller chunks and parses them to their desired data type
out_list = []
for line in lines:
    ldict = {}
    line = line.split(separator)
    for a in line:
        attribute = a.strip()
        chunks = attribute.split('=')
        try:#write chunk
            ldict[chunks[0]] = chunks[1]
        except IndexError:
            pass
    out_list.append(ldict)
return out_list
```

PS: I had these functions already lying around, regular expressions might make them much more elegant.

For more info:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open